# Adsense Ads not showing up on site - Admob acc

Tags: seo, google-adsense

I have existing admob adsense account 5 months old. Now i need to apply ads on my site.

IN adsense i have registered and mysite and i got options to create ad codes. Now after using ad codes on site only blank area is coming no ads are coming.

Its already more than a week .

What could be the issue  ?

Comment: Admob and Adsense has different review process. You may have an active admob account, but the Adsense on the same account still need to be reviewed and approved to be able to serve ads to your site.